# Print Map Value.If the argument is a key in the map,prints associated value otherwise prints an output that the key is not present

Tags: java

My code so far is working but I have been sitting and reading about get(Object Key) for last two days and just don't know how to apply in separate method with single argument. Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
 public class Restaurant
{

 private final HashMap<Integer, List<String>>restaurant;
 private int order;
 private int order2;

 /**   * Constructor for objects of class Restaurant
  */

 public Restaurant()
 {

   restaurant = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();

   }


  public void TableOrder()
 {
   List<String> order = new ArrayList<>();

   order.add("Baked Ham with Brown Sugar Mustard Glaze");
   order.add("Asparagus and Cheese Tart");
   order.add("Classic Deviled Eggs");
   restaurant.put(1, order);

    List<String> order2 = new ArrayList<>();
    order2.add("Macaroni and Cheese");
    order2.add("Creamy Spring Peas with Pancetta");
    order2.add("Four-Cheese Scalloped Potatoes");
    restaurant.put(2, order2);
  }

  public void printMap() {

  Set set = restaurant.entrySet();
  Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
   while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
     System.out.print("Table"+ " "+ e.getKey()+ " " 
     + System.lineSeparator() + "Order:"+ System.lineSeparator() );


     System.out.println(e.getValue());


     public void printMapValue() {
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: if `(restaurant.get(key) == null)`, print "key is not present", otherwise print `restaurant.get(key)`

Comment: if {restaurant.get(key) <------ can not find variable key

Answer (score 2):

With Java8, you can do something like:

```
System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(key, "no entry for key: " + key));
```

for example. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-).

Comment: @user9755736 That is why I told you that you have **two** problems. I can help you with *how* to do such a thing. But the work of sitting down and fixing your broken *syntax* is something that you have to work on. The strategy is to **comment** out large parts of your file, and then step by step bring them back.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Getting there slowly